# how to place a button on crm 2011 form.

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I want to place a button on CRM 2011 form.

```
function create_button(fldName, btnLabel, btnWidth, evt) 
{
try{
fldName = "inmate_button_submit";
btnLable="Click Me";
// btnWidth="200px";


var btn = '<button class="ms-crm-Button" onclick="evt()" style="width:50px" id="' +      fldName + '" onmouseover="Mscrm.ButtonUtils.hoverOn(this);"  onmouseout="Mscrm.ButtonUtils.hoverOff(this);" >Click Me</button>';

var ctrl = null;

try {
    ctrl = Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get(fldName).get_chromeElement()[0];
} catch (e) {
    ctrl = Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get(fldName)._control.get_element();
}

// Add the new button
ctrl.innerHTML += btn;

// Hide the textbox
ctrl.children[0].style.display = 'none';
ctrl.children[1].style.display = 'none';

// Hide the label
Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get(fldName).setLabel(btnLable);

// Add Event to the newly created button
 ctrl.children[0].attachEvent('onclick', evt);

}
catch(e){alert(e.description);}
  }
function evt()
{
alert("You have clicked me!!");
}
```

The above is my following code which places the button on the form. When i click on the button, after showing the alert crm gives me the following error.

*ERROR
An error has occurred.
Try this action again. If the problem continues, check the Microsoft Dynamics CRM Community or you for solutions or contact....*

I have no idea why this is happening. Any help guys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that using getElementById is going to be unsupported and may not work (does not work in Outlook 2007) in some browsers.

I would recommend placing this is in a web resource, or utilizing the ribbon for this functionality. Would either of those meet your requirements?

Comment: I would definitely second Nick's suggestion here, you should really be using the Form Ribbon for such functionality.

Comment: You know what I think it would meet the requirement. Knowing the client I know they would have some reservations but I think I will be able to explain them that putting a button on the form wont work. 

But can I trigger a web service(which this button is supposed to do eventually) from a button on ribbon?

Answer (score 1):

If you use your js as a webresource then you shouldnt have any problems.

Or you can even trigger the function OnLoad

Please see following :

http://www.mscrmconsultant.com/2012/07/insert-custom-button-on-crm-form-using.html

Comment: The js is being used as a web resource and is triggered OnLoad function of the form.

Answer (score 0):

i will recommend add custom webresource ( HTML page which contanis javascript functionality on in onload event ) if you need access to form, use window.parent.document.Xrm.Page ....

Answer (score 0):

2 things might cause this issue:

1. evt function is not accessible to your button

Resolution: try registering the evt function in global scope i.e.

```
evt = function() { alert("…"); }
```

or

```
window.evt = function() {}
```

2.   Your button is using the same field name as the placeholder field. 
This might cause internal issues.

Resolution: Try giving your button another (bogus) id instead i.e. fieldname + "_button"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the 3rd party applications...

http://crmvisualribbonedit.codeplex.com/

Call the function from a web resource. 
NOTE: Remember to add $ to reference the web resource location
Example $webresource:ButtonScript.js